# Merges using github web UI use a different time zone than commits

Tags: git

I notice that the commits I make to git use the time zone of my system clock, but when I do merges using the github Web UI, a different time zone is used (where I am physically located).  You can see the difference using `git show` whose 4th line shows the date of the commit (or merge), including its time zone offset.

So for my commit, which I did on the command line, `git show` produces `Date:   Wed Jan 17 14:34:48 2024 -0800`, but for the merge (which I did on github) I did about 20 minutes later, it shows `Date:   Thu Jan 18 00:56:27 2024 +0200`.

Where does the github Web UI get its timezone from? Could it be getting it from location data? (+0200 is where I am physically located, despite the timezone setting on my laptop, which is -0800).

Comment: What's the problem? The times are correct. The commit is Wed Jan 17 14:34:48 2024 -0800, and the merge is Thu Jan 18 00:56:27 2024 +0200 which is the same as Wed Jan 17 14:56:27 2024 -0800 — about 20 minutes after the commit, just as you expect.

Comment: I would be more surprised if GitHub used your system clock rather than sniffing out your current location.

Comment: @matt I realize that, but I'm just confused why github doesn't use the same timezone as git from the command line on the same machine

Comment: @Guildenstern, could git from the command line also sniff the location if that was desired (meaning adding code to so that)?

Comment: @JoelFan I think it would be weird for a CLI tool to try to sniff your real location.